# How to play 3gp video file with intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, 3gp

I want to play .3gp video file in my android tablet. i tried below code, but it throws an error message. How can I play with default video player in android?

```
String movieurl = root + "/" + fileNameTextView.getText().toString();           
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
Uri data = Uri.parse(movieurl); 
intent.setDataAndType(data,"video/3gpp"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

And this is the error message:

> 11-15 13:47:11.060: E/AndroidRuntime(23061):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20121002_174209.3gp typ=video/3gpp }

Comment: Could you just try `video/*`

Comment: I tried that. Still gives the same error message. But if I browse to the file and click on it the Gallery player starts and plays the file fine.

Comment: I just found out that it works on Samsung Galaxy Tablet but doesn't work on Motorola Xoom. What could be wrong?

Comment: And both of them have Android version 4.0.4

Comment: The Motorola Xoom is saving video files in 3gp format, but Samsung Galaxy saves them in mp4 format. Both have the same operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have changed the String movieurl by adding "file:///" to the beginning:

```
String movieurl = "file:///" + root + "/" + fileNameTextView.getText().toString();
```

and that fixed the issue.